# Bone sizing won't work

Tags: armature, bones

When I try to change the thickness of the bones by pressing crtl alt S, nothing happens.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: are you in Edit Mode? And have you switched the Armature Display to BBones?

Comment: could you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: Not every kind of bones have tickness, only "B-Bones" and "Envelope".

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the size of the bones you need to be in the edit mode.  You can enter edit mode by selecting the object and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>.